# Set the position of an object as an inline style to itself?

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I am trying to build a responsive design of 8 divs. I need those divs to have an inline CSS style of absolute positioning with left and top positions. In order to keep it responsive I cant position them with CSS.

I want to wait until the divs load then use jQuery to grab the position's of those divs then pass that information back into their respective inline styles.

If I use document ready it applies left:0, right:0 to all my divs. If I use document load it doesn't fire the code at all.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.item").each(function(i, obj) {
    var posfix = $(this).position();
    var getW = $(this).width();
    var getH = $(this).height();
    $(this).children().text( "left: " + posfix.left + ", top: " + posfix.top );//test
    $(this).children().append( "height: " + getH + ", width: " + getW );//test
    $(this).css({position: 'absolute',left:posfix.left,top:posfix.top,width:getW,height:getH});//set
   });
});
```

Test code here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xuzPF/18/)

Comment: Try with the help of giving unique id to each div. you can easily assign the css. in your case every div have same class name.

Comment: Where do you calculate the new position? As I can see the divs are starting from 0px (default) and you are reassigning the same value.

Comment: @Vaibhav Jain - Im essentially repeating the same action over and over again in which is why im using the single class name to repeat without having to write code for each individual ID.

Comment: @Mangiucugna - That's the initial problem when the code runs it returns a 0px/0px for every div. I can perform a .text() to test the code and it will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).load(function()
{
  //your code here
});
```

There is no such thing as document load. :)

Also you might want to try offset() which returns the postion relative to the document (postion() returns the postion relative to the **parent**.

For more info check this out - [offset](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Comment: If I use window.load it returns the same issue as doc.ready. I will research the offset to see if it offers the right solution.

Thanks for the correction on document load.

Comment: You were correct about using .offset() it is returning the correct information needed. However the main issue still remains of applying the code to each individual element just as the text script works.